# Programmatically delete the contents of SharePoint 2013 recycle bin

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Scenario:

- Client would like a PowerShell script wrote to delete the 2nd stage recycle bin for a SharePoint 2013 Site Collection
- Client's SharePoint requires a credential authorization on load.
  Issue:
- I have researched, however in regards to SharePoint 2013, I have yet to find a script example that involves using my credentials. However in the SharePoint Online examples for programmatically deleting a SP recycle bin they use credential authorization.
- My attempts to splice these two scripts together have been met with no success.

Question: Would somone be able to assist me by taking a look at my code and letting me know where I am going wrong?

```
##Variables for Processing
 $SiteUrl = "https://MySite/sites/site"



 Try {
     #Setup the context
     $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
     $Context.Credentials = $Credentials

     #Get the recycle bin
     $Site = $Context.Site
     $RecycleBinItems = $Site.RecycleBin
     $Context.Load($Site)
     $Context.Load($RecycleBinItems)
     $Context.ExecuteQuery()

     Write-Host "Total Number of Items found Recycle Bin:" $RecycleBinItems.Count
     #sharepoint online powershell empty recycle bin
     $RecycleBinItems.DeleteAll()
     $Context.ExecuteQuery()
 }
 catch {
     write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
 }
```

Comment: Remove the `>>` characters as this makes a copy and paste difficult. What errors are you getting when you run the script?

Comment: >> Characters are removed, and the error I am receiving is as follows. "Error: Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded." Not sure if im using the wrong one seeing as I took that part from a tutorial for SharePoint Online when I am currently dealing with SharePoint 2013.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/add-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-snap-in-to-all-powershell-windows

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rcormier/sharepoint-online-and-csom-a-quick-lesson-in-poor-error-messages